# Автокорректировка текста на python при распозновании речи

Tags: python-3.x, распознавание-речи, vosk

Vosk распознает мне речь, далее мне нужно распознанный текст вставить в файл или документ. Допустим: добрый день сегодня день открытий. Распознается как: Дообр эй ден секотня день открыто.

Можно ли как-нибудь этой же библиотекой откорректировать или хотя бы адекватно распознать речь?

Принимается любой ответ по теме распознования речи и повышения точности распознования.